# Trait 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory' not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have downgrade my Laravel project from Laravel 8 to Laravel 7 because of some dependency . Now i am including "Vonage" for the video calling and my  "guzzlehttp/guzzle" is on 7.0.1 . As  Vonage API PHP SDK depends on version 6 of GuzzleHTTP but Laravel 8 uses version 7 . As the archititure of laravel 7 is diffrent from laravel 8 .I need to update GuzzleHTTP  from my composer and On updating my composer It shows this error:

> Trait 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory' not found

this is because of architecture of Laravel 8. Is their any possible way that I can update my composer?

Also, this project is a large scale project so I can't re create this project on Laravel 7.

Comment: Why are you trying to downgrade the application? This is generally a bad idea. You should address whatever problem led you to this decision in a different way.

Comment: yeah that is annoying as hell i also created an app on Laravel 8 but some of the dependencies doesn't support Laravel 8 yet and i didn't found any solution. so i created the app again on Laravel 7 :D

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper . because i am trying to use "Vonage " for the video calling . This is because the Vonage API PHP SDK depends on version 6 of GuzzleHTTP but Laravel 8 uses version 7 of GuzzleHTTP.

Comment: remove that trait from your models ....

Comment: @lagbox Removing trait would not solve my problem because as i need to downgrade my "guzzlehttp/guzzle" for the Vonage

Comment: If you want to downgrade your project for `guzzleHTTP^6.0` for a third-party API, you can just try to downgrade your `guzzleHTTP` and then try to fetch from that API. Laravel 8 have support of `guzzleHTTP^6.0`. But, remember to backup your entire source if anything doesn't go as planned. Check this answer for [downgrading guide](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/guzzlehttp-error-while-upgrading-laravel-to-8-from-7)

Comment: What do you mean by "update my composer"? How is this even related to Composer itself?

Comment: @NicoHaase I mean "composer update "  sir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trait `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory` has been introduced in Laravel v8. It does not exist in Laravel v7, so you have to remove it from your code. The error message you have seen should show you more details about the file that uses the trait

Comment: Thanks for note. Also, I type and run this command in the terminal 'composer dump-autoload' then the error is gone